# Meteor.js - Loop through array of objects

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have a small list building application, pretty much a to do list.

I have one collection called 'lists'

```
Lists = new Meteor.Collection('lists')
```

I have a form which submits to this collection, and that works fine.

My template is here:

```
<template name="list">
  {{#with list}}
    <ul>
    {{#each links}}
    <li>PLEASE WORK! >>>> {{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

My helpers are here:

```
  Template.list.helpers({
    list: function () {
      currentListId = Session.get('currentListId')
      return Lists.find({
        _id : currentListId
      });
    },
    title: function () {
      return this.title
    }
  })
```

I know I am subscribed to the database because when I do:

```
Lists.find({_id : currentListId}).fetch()
```

It returns an object which looks like

```
_id: "mrkpjGW2"
createdAt: 1447401698770
items: Array[3]
__proto__: Object
```

and inside items

```
items: Array[3]
    0: Object
        createdAt: 1447402263732
        owner: "3oyKZKhdPZyDkWnZm"
        title: "google.com"
        __proto__: Objec
```

So I want to loop over items, and get the title.

Comment: Why not `{{#each items}}`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `links` helper. You iterate over links, but is it defined? Also you have different template names in your example - `list` in HTML code and `linkList` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You have {{#each links}} but what is links? I don't see it defined anywhere.

When you return...

```
list: function () {
      currentListId = Session.get('currentListId')
      return Lists.find({
        _id : currentListId
      });
    }
```

You can iterate over that directly, so rather then {{#with list}} at the top, take that out and just use {{#each list}} below.

```
<template name="list">
    <ul>
    {{#each list}}
    <li>PLEASE WORK! >>>> {{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already used helper to give lists to blaze, and that is sufficient, no need to create a helper for title as well. You can iterate items and fetch title directly from blaze.
From what I understand, you want to iterate over items array, and fetch title from each item. So, in javascript,

```
Template.list.helpers({
    list: function () {
        currentListId = Session.get('currentListId')
        return Lists.find({
        _id : currentListId
      }).fetch();
    }
  })
```

In your html,

```
<template name="list">
    <ul>
        {{#each list}}
            <li>PLEASE WORK! >>>> {{title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```